# Validar si las mismas palabras existen dentro de un array

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos array y quiero validar si en el array con mayor longitud están todas las palabras del array pequeño y si es así retornar un true, si el array pequeño no está completo en el array grande debería retornar false

```
var a1 = ['Casa', 'Azul', 'Familiar'];
var a2 = ['Casa', 'Azul', 'Familiar', 'Unidad cerrada'];

Array.prototype.includes = function (getArray) {
  if (this.length != getArray.length) return false;

  for (var i = 0; i < getArray.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] instanceof Array && getArray[i] instanceof Array) {
      if (!this[i].includes(getArray[i])) return false;
    } else if (this[i] != getArray[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};

console.log("Comparando a1 and a2", a1.includes(a2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un Ejemplo con solo For y comparación:

```js
var a1 = ['Casa', 'Azul', 'Familiar'];
var a2 = ['Casa', 'Azul', 'Familiar', 'Unidad cerrada'];

function comparar(a1,a2)
{
    var total=0;    
  if(a1.length>a2.length)
  {
    var mayor="A1";
  var total_menor=a2.length;
    for(i=0;i<=a1.length;i++)
  {for(a=0;a<=a2.length;a++){
        if(a2[a]==a1[i] && a2[a]!=undefined){
        total++;}
}}}
else
{
    var mayor="A2";
  var total_menor=a1.length;
    for(i=0;i<=a2.length;i++)
  {for(a=0;a<=a1.length;a++){
        if(a1[a]==a2[i] && a1[a]!=undefined){
        total++;}
  }}}
  var estado=total==total_menor? "True":"False";
  console.log("El Mayor es "+mayor+" y hay "+total+"/"+total_menor+" Del menor en el Mayor ("+estado+")");
}

comparar(a1,a2);
```

PD: El true lo puse escrito puedes retornar lo que desees

Answer (score 0):

No sé hasta qué punto es buena idea sobreescribir el método includes, ya que array.prototype debería ser readonly. De todas formas, utilizando ese mismo método se puede hacer de forma sencilla:

```
function isArrayContained(innerArray, outerArray) {
  for (const element of innerArray) {
    if (!outerArray.includes(element)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aca te dejo una opcion de una sola linea utilizando el metodo Every.

En lugar de ponerme a buscar cual es el mas largo de los dos, comparo en ambas direcciones.

Si manualmente podes elegir cual es el array menor, podes retirar la opcion del || (or) y te queda mas simple aun.

```js
var a0 = ['Casa', 'Azul', 'Familiar',"perro"];

var a1 = ['Casa', 'Azul', 'Familiar'];

var a2 = ['Casa', 'Azul', 'Familiar', 'Unidad cerrada'];

const compare = (a, b) => a.every( i => b.includes(i) ) || b.every( i => a.includes(i) );

console.log("Donde si se cumple");
console.log( compare(a1,a2) );
console.log( compare(a2,a1) );

console.log("Donde no se cumple");
console.log( compare(a0,a2) );
console.log( compare(a2,a0) );
```